# Doc files get corrupted when created on Device but not on Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, itext

I'm using iTextG to create 5 doc files from a pdf. When I do it on the Android Studio Emulator they open just fine but when I try it on my phone (note 4) the doc files get corrupted for some reason. Here's the code...

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(root + "/downloadedfile.pdf");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(root + "/" + day + ".doc"));
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((float) ((float) 28 + 107*(dayNum-1) + 0.5), 0, (float) ((float) 28 + 107*dayNum + 0.5), reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight());
    RenderFilter regionFilter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), regionFilter);
    out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1, strategy));
    reader.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Edit: root = getcachedir().toString() ... (I've tried other directories)

Comment: can you post any logcat?

Comment: """new FileOutputStream(root + "/" + day + ".doc")""" doesn't generate a .doc file. It outputs a file that has the .doc extension and contains the bytes of the text on page 1 of the PDF file. If you want to create .doc files, you'll need to look into another library than iText. iText only deals with PDF files.